# How do I keep my alternate CD upgrade from using the network?

Tags: upgrade, alternate

I'm running an upgrade from Maverick to Natty from a mounted 'alternate' ISO, but it's current status is "Fetching file 1444 of 1703 at 55.1 kB/s". I'm pretty sure it's trying to use the network for the "Getting new packages" phase. How can I make sure it uses only the ISO, and not the network? Disconnecting the network (or keeping it disconnected the entire time) just results in stalling (waiting, not freezing) during the "Getting new packages" phase.

I've followed [the instructions on the Ubuntu Wiki for upgrading using the Alternate CD ISO mounted as a drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NattyUpgrades#Upgrading%20Using%20the%20Alternate%20CD/DVD). Also, I selected "No" to the question about updating packages during the upgrade.

If this is a bug, please give a link with the bug number or tell me that I should file a bug.

Comment: In case anyone is tempted to ask, yes, I verified that the ISO file didn't have errors; I used [Transmission](https://launchpad.net/transmission) to download and verify it.

Comment: I tried running `gksu /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade` from the terminal, and it outputs `WARNING: Failed to read mirror file` at the beginning of the "Setting new software channels" step. Perhaps that has something to do with it?

Comment: I just had the same problem - said "no" to the download question, and it still tries to download. I just think about pulling the network cable, but when you say this does not help ...

Comment: [This bug 353825](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/353825) describes the same symptom. I'm not sure it has the same cause here.

Comment: @Paulo: Yeah, there weren't any packages in a broken state.

Comment: I've updated the question just in case it turns out to be a bug. I still think it's probably a user error, though.

Comment: It's not a user error - Update Manager says it won't use the network, and then uses it anyway: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/875639

Answer (score 2):

Using the **Alternative CD**, and not unplugging the Ethernet (before) boot, does NOT behave the same as answering: NO.

Have you tried, with the network cable umplugged?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with the network cable unplugged.

Comment: This has solved issue for me (in past), but I unplugged Ethernet cable **before** boot ..

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. My solution was to uncheck all software repositories, then the upgrade from cd worked.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [upgrade instructions on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NattyUpgrades#Upgrading%20Using%20the%20Alternate%20CD/DVD):

Burn the ISO to a CD and insert it in your computer OR mount the ISO using:

```
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso /media/cdrom
```

When done, run the upgrade application from the CD:

```
gksu /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade
```

Follow the instructions, when askes whether you want to download updates from the internet, choose **No**.

Comment: :) That's exactly what I did: see the second paragraph of my question.

Comment: @Firefeather: have you got the right ISO? I almost messed my system up by using an ubuntu ISO instead of a kubuntu one for my Kubuntu system.

Comment: Great troubleshooting question, but I am using `ubuntu-11.04-alternate-i386.iso` to upgrade Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit. Shouldn't be any problems there.

Answer (score 0):

The alternate cd does not have everything on it.  I recently did this using the dvd image and it seemed to only download one or two things ( I didn't answer no to the question ).  Maybe you have a bunch of packages installed that are not on the alternate cd so it has no choice but to download them?

Comment: I would think that if a package wasn't in the default install (thus on the alternate CD), one of two things would happen: (1) The upgrade breaks the package's dependencies, so the upgrade program sets it to be removed and notifies you of that decision; or (2) The upgrade doesn't affect the package's dependencies, and answering "No" makes the "repository" on the CD the only one that the upgrade program's aware of, so, not seeing anything affecting that package, it leaves the package alone. Do you know of something that says anything to the contrary?